# How can I get notification of page load events in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, setwindowshookex

I need to be able to monitor navigation events (such as page loads or switching between active tabs) in browsers running on a Windows PC. So far, I can get this to work in IE and Firefox by loading a DLL into all running apps via a call to SetWindowsHookEx, then asking for either the IHTMLDocument2 (in IE) or nsIWebProgress (in Firefox) interface from the application.  I can use the appropriate interface to request a callback from the application when an event of interest happens.

Is there a way to do this in Chrome?  I have read a little about Chrome extensions, but I have not found any documentation on an API exposed by Chrome that is analogous to COM in IE or XPCOM in Firefox.  Will a similar approach work or will I need to do something completely different?  (I am working in C++.)

I would appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: There are API that may satisfy your needs. Can you give more details about *all* the events you want to track?

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome extensions API you can register some events handlers for changing state of tab like when document state is changed (loading or loaded), when new tab is added/removed from window or when user switch between tabs.
More about tabs events You find on http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActiveChanged